# How to set new AUTO_INCREMENT value?

Tags: 7, testing

I have the following statement in my module code:

```
db_query("ALTER TABLE {tripletex_invoice} AUTO_INCREMENT = :number", array(':number' => $start_value));
```

During [SimpleTest](https://www.drupal.org/project/Simpletest) I get the following error message:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''20000'' at
line 1: ALTER TABLE {tripletex_invoice} AUTO_INCREMENT = :value; Array ( 
[:value] => 20000 ) in _tripletex_add_invoice_log() (line 1769 of 
/var/www/d7/sites/all/modules/tripletex/tripletex.module).
```

Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Parameter replacement only works for `WHERE` clauses, it won't work for the kind of query you're trying to run.

You need to insert `$start_value` directly into the query string. If that value comes from an un-trustworthy source then obviously you need to sanitise it and make sure it falls within the correct bounds yourself:

```
$start_value = (int)$start_value; // Make sure it's an integer

// Do any other checks you need to here (bounds checking, etc.)

// Build the query string and run it
$sql = "ALTER TABLE {tripletex_invoice} AUTO_INCREMENT = $start_value";
db_query($sql);
```